# How to send push notifications recurring at user specified time intervals (5min,10min..etc)?

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

I'm building an app where I need to send notifications recurring at time intervals specified by user (like 5 or 10 minutes). I saw how to send notifications at a specific time everyday using alarm manager. How can I send notifications after every 5 or 10 (user specified) minutes (hours)?

Answer (score 2):

you can use elascaped realtime waker in this example code the alarm will be there every 30 minutes for notification you can use android notification manager, let me know if that helps

```
 alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR,
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, alarmIntent);
```

you can refer to the following links for more information

[notification manager android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

[Android alarm reference](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)

Comment: please mark it as solved if it this answer solved your problem